# Capture debug output in C#

Tags: c#, debugging, listener, capture

Is it possible to capture debug output (create debug listener) in C#?

I'd like to have functionality like [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx) has, but I'd like to log debug output to SQL Server. Or maybe a better way would be to make DebugView log to a file, and then feed the file to SQL Server?

I've implemented `TraceListener` and added it to `Debug.Listeners` collection, but it seems to capture debug only from my application. What I want to do is to capture debug from all applications. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It would be difficult to capture information from other applications. For instance, how could you know how my application outputs debug information, unless I told you. Yet, in nearly all cases only "released" code is deployed, so there is no "debug" information. Therefore, capturing the information that DebugView provides (through Windows Debug) is about as much as you can reasonably expect.

Comment: @AMissico - I know other applications output debug information because they are compiled so. I have already said that I'd like to do the same thing that DebugView does, but store the debug information into the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*DbMon.NET - A simple .NET OutputDebugString capturer* at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/DbMonNET.aspx seems to do what you want.

Answer (score -2):

Unless you truly have a specific need to roll your own logger, I would use an existing logging framework such as [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/). It has an ADO.NET appender that you can configure to log debug or trace output directly to SQL Server.

Comment: I need to capture debug output from other applications, not just mine, so this is not about 'where to log stuff', but 'how to log stuff from other apps'