# Is it possible to display VS Output window content in my application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

Long story short: some third party unmanaged dll, which I use in my project, apparently dumps its errors into Visual Studio Output window (shows output from "Debug") during runtime. It looks like this:

```
 *** WARNING  ERROR 11 from R3ORP.  The degree 0 polynomial fit is a perfect
 ***          fit within machine precision.
     Here is a traceback of subprogram calls in reverse order:
     Routine name                    Error type  Error code
     ------------                    ----------  ----------
     R3ORP                                6          11    (Called internally)
     R4ORP                                0           0    (Called internally)
     R2ORP                                0           0    (Called internally)
     R2URV                                0           0    (Called internally)
     RCURV                                0           0
     USER                                 0           0
```

I want to either log these errors or display them in my application. 
Is it possible to somehow access the VS output stream from my application? Can I still do it without VS attached to process? I don't need the entire stream, but I want to catch those "warnings" somehow. I've tried adding listeners to `Diagnostics.Debug` and `Diagnostics.Trace`, didn't work.

Comment: Use  [Console.SetOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: "I've tried adding listeners to `Diagnostics.Debug` and `Diagnostics.Trace`, didn't work." Show use what you attempted, because it is indeed one way to go.

Comment: @ORdia, didn't work either. :( Apparently, Output window aggregates messages from various different sources, so far I cant seem to find the source, which generates those errors. But it is not, `Trace`, it is not `Debug` and it is not `Console`.

Answer (score 1):

There is! You can implement your own TraceListener-Class.

First write the TraceListener-Class:

```
class CustomTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    public string  AllMessages { get; set; }

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        AllMessages += message;
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string o)
    {
        Write(o + '\n');
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return AllMessages;
    }
}
```

You can of cause implement custom behavior (like writing to a Textbox etc) in the `Write()` method.

Then you just have to add an instance of your class to the system's debug trace listeners and you're good:

```
CustomTraceListener myTraceListener = new CustomTraceListener();
Debug.Listeners.Add(myTraceListener);
Debug.WriteLine("this is a test");
Debug.WriteLine("this is another test");
string result = myTraceListener.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I explained in one of my comments, this approach does not work for me. :(

Answer (score 1):

That's a really fascinating question here.

I found a Solution with the `System.Diagnostics.TraceListener` class.

```
sealed class StackOverflowSampleListener : TraceListener
{
    // Singleton 
    public static readonly StackOverflowSampleListener Instance =
      new StackOverflowSampleListener();

    public void InitializeTracing(bool ReadDebugOutput)
    {
         if (ReadDebugOutput == true)
            Debug.Listeners.Add(this);
        else
            Trace.Listeners.Add(this);
    }

    public StringBuilder Buffer = new StringBuilder();

    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        // Do something with your messages!
        Buffer.Append(message);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        // Do something with your messages!
        Buffer.Append(message);
    }
}
```

Example in some Form.cs Code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        StackOverflowSampleListener.Instance.InitializeTracing(true);

        StackOverflowSampleListener.Instance.Buffer.ToString();
    }
```

---

GuyMontag is absolutly right with his answer, but i prefer a lighter version with an singleton implementation and the possibility collection messages also in the release mode (look at initialize methode).

Comment: Thank you for your aswer. Sadly, as I mentioned in my question, I have already tried adding listeners to `Diagnostics.Debug` and `Diagnostics.Trace` - it didn't work. I mean, it does capture messages sent to Output using those classes. But it clearly does not capture *all* the messages in output, including messages from third-party unmanaged dll I am intersted in.

Answer (score 1):

If this is an unmanaged dll, and the output appears in the Visual Studio output window, that means it is using the [OutputDebugString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to write the data.

Because this data is meant for debugging only, there is no guarantee that subsequent versions will still output this info, or stick to the same format.
If that is of no concern to you, a quick google search on 'c# capture debug output' yields [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2809454/4928207).

Comment: No, neither DebugView nor the class which listens to OutputDebugString capture those errors. >_< Must be something else, I guess. But an interesting read, nonetheless.

Comment: Can you link the component issuing those messages?

Comment: @NikitaBrizhak The Debug output can have one subscriber only,
so when you are debugging the application with the component, Visual Studio will catch the output.

To work around the issue you could try to capture output to the functions OutputDebugStringA and OutputDebugStringW manually with for example [EasyHook](https://easyhook.codeplex.com/).

Comment: no, I can't link the library itself, as I have no right to distribute it. But I am fairly certain that the messages originate in `Intel Fortran` binaries, which this library uses internally. I could not find any info, that would help me figure out how those messages are sent or how VS captures them though.