# How to capture Visual Studio's "system debugger" messages in Output panel to the C# WPF application I built?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

First, let me say that I don't know what is the exact keyword should I use to search this. I only came up with the title of this question.

I'm sure that most of the people who has been using Visual Studio are already familiar with its Output panel that prints debug information, etc. Some messages in it are outputted by the "system debugger" itself (how should I call it?), and we can write a message ourself to it by `Console.Write()`, `Console.WriteLine()`, `Debug.Write()`, etc.

What I want to know, is there any way to **capture messages that are output by the "system debugger" itself to the application that I built**?

If you still can't understand what I mean, look at the illustration below:

You can see that this messages are not outputted by me manually, it's by the "system debugger":

[image: Visual Studio's Output panel]

And I want to show them in my application, say, in a `TextBlock` like this:

[image: Illustration of what I want to do]

---

**EDIT:**

As @Andy's answer suggested... I've done every step correctly. But, apparently, it can **only** show debug output from a manually written debugging like `Debug.Write()`/`WriteLine()` or `Trace.Write()`/`WriteLine()`. So, his answer doesn't satisfy my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a new class that derives from [`TraceListener`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener(v=vs.110).aspx), and then add an instance of that class to the [`Debug.Listeners`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.listeners(v=vs.110).aspx) collection, your class should be called whenever something is written to the debug output in Visual Studio.

At a high level, I would implement it something like this:

- In the class that derives from `TraceListener`, add an event. Fire this event whenever any of the `Write()` methods is called, and include the text in the `EventArgs` of the event.
- In the main window, create an instance of your `TraceListener`. Add it to the `Debug.Listeners` collection, and subscribe to the event.
- In the handler for your `TraceListener`'s event, add the text from the `EventArgs` to the `TextBlock`.

Comment: Could you show me how to implement it so that the debug output is updated on my `TextBlock` of a `MainWindow` every time there's new incoming debug messages? I've read about how to [implement a custom TraceListener](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_misc/debuggingandtracing/article.php/c5611/Implementing-a-Custom-TraceListener.htm) but I can't get myself to make it works on C#.

Comment: @softtama I don't have time to implement the solution, however I did add a high level overview of how I'd implement it. Does that help?

Comment: I have implemented it. Apparently it can only show debug output from a manually written debugging like `Debug.Write()`/`WriteLine()` or `Trace.Write()`/`WriteLine()`. What I want to log is that what I called "system debugger" messages.

Comment: @softtama I'm not sure how to do that off hand - sorry. :(

Comment: It's okay, I do appreciate your effort for helping me. I'm hoping that you will come back with the right exact solution :)

Comment: @softtama I thought about it some more, and I'm not sure it's possible. I think you'd have to register your application as a debugger to get more than what the debug listeners get you. And that would probably get you all debug messages from any process running on your system, not just your own process.

Answer (score 0):

In effect you are answering the same question as this [Capture debug output in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809064/capture-debug-output-in-c-sharp)

so you can use the answer to that question

or alternative use MS DebugView tool as explained here https://wpf.2000things.com/2017/06/29/1212-viewing-wpf-trace-output-outside-of-visual-studio/